# How to create condition next even the error is "the index out of range"

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, beautifulsoup

it's my first time using python, and i still learn about python. I have problem when i tried to using index. Index show the error "IndexError: list index out of range". But i want to pass or create condition next for it. Example like this :

```
    links = "http://www.website_name.com/"
    content_ig = BeautifulSoup(send.content, 'html.parser')
    script = content_ig.find_all("script")[3].get_text()
    script  = script.split('openData = ')[1][:-1]
    if not script:
        #This condition i create to next if the value is out of index
    else:
        print("Works")
```

I mean when the index out of the range, i want create condition the next to another value, not just stop and show the error "IndexError: list index out of range".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your question, you can wrap your line of code inside a [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) brace:

```
try:
    script  = script.split('openData = ')[1][:-1]
    print("Works")
except IndexError:
    ... # code to run if the value is out of index
```

Quick demo:

```
In [1739]: x = [0]

In [1740]: try:
      ...:     print(x[1]) # only 1 element in x, so this is invalid 
      ...: except IndexError:
      ...:     print("List out of range!")
      ...:     
List out of range!
```

Comment: @Scarlettstone Glad to help. :)